# automatically redirect page in angularjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

In a angularjs project, I want when user doesn't sign in, page is automatically redirect to login page. For this, I when user want see a page, if doesn't sign in before, I send `401` from rails sever by below code:

```
def failure
    render :status => 401, :json => { :success => false, :info => "Login Credentials Failed" }
  end
```

and I recieve this in chrome browser:

```
 GET http://localhost:3000/api/record.json 401 (Unauthorized) angular.min.js?body=1:81
(anonymous function) angular.min.js?body=1:81
t angular.min.js?body=1:76
f angular.min.js?body=1:74
I angular.min.js?body=1:102
I angular.min.js?body=1:102
(anonymous function) angular.min.js?body=1:103
h.$eval angular.min.js?body=1:114
h.$digest angular.min.js?body=1:111
h.$apply angular.min.js?body=1:115
t angular.min.js?body=1:75
y angular.min.js?body=1:79
x.onreadystatechange
```

And I have below code in angularjs controller to redirect page:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app',['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'sessionService', 'recordService'])
        .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
            var interceptor = ['$location', '$rootScope', '$q', function($location, $rootScope, $q) {
                function success(response) {
                    return response
                };

                function error(response) {
                    if (response.status == 401) {
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('event:unauthorized');
                        $location.path('/users/login');
                        return response;
                    };
                    return $q.reject(response);
                };

                return function(promise) {
                    return promise.then(success, error);
                };
            }];

//            $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
        }])
        .config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
            $routeProvider
                    .when('/',               {controller: 'HomeCtrl',    templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('templates/index.html') %>'})
                    .when('/record',         {controller: 'RecordCtrl',  templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('templates/record/index.html') %>'})
                    .when('/users/login',    {controller: 'UsersCtrl',   templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('templates/users/login.html') %>'})
                    .when('/users/register', {controller: 'UsersCtrl',   templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('templates/users/register.html') %>'})
                    .otherwise(              {redirectTo: '/'});
        }]);
```

Now when I run project and I want accept `localhost:3000/#/record`, I see the record page without data and page doesn't redirect to login page. How can I fix this probelm and solve it?

Comment: at the first I want to say what is the not good idea to do redirection in intercpeter, you firing event event:unauthorized you can catch this event in your root Controller and do your redirection in that place , and also you sure what your interceptor works on error ? did you putted debuger in error function ?

Comment: Check this link p://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969835/angularjs-login-and-authentication-in-each-route-and-controller

Comment: What angular version you have ?

Comment: version of angular: angular-1.3.0-beta.14.

Comment: nice  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'); :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like:

```
angular.module('myapp')
    .factory('httpInterceptor', ['$q', '$location',function ($q, $location) {
        var canceller = $q.defer();
        return {
            'request': function(config) {
                // promise that should abort the request when resolved.
                config.timeout = canceller.promise;
                return config;
            },
            'response': function(response) {
                return response;
            },
            'responseError': function(rejection) {
                if (rejection.status === 401) {
                    canceller.resolve('Unauthorized'); 
                    $location.url('/user/signin');
                }
                if (rejection.status === 403) {
                    canceller.resolve('Forbidden');  
                    $location.url('/');
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }

        };
    }
    ])
    //Http Intercpetor to check auth failures for xhr requests
   .config(['$httpProvider',function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
    }]);
```

than in the route

```
.state('user_actions', {
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'users/views/actions.html',
            resolve: {
                hasaccess: function(Sessions){
                    return Sessions.hasAccess('users');
                } 
            },
            controller:'UserParentActionsController'
        })
        .state('user_actions.create', {
            url: '/user/create',
            templateUrl: 'users/views/create.html',
            resolve: {
                groups: function(Groups){
                   return Groups.getList();
                }
            },
            controller:'UserCreateController'
        })
```

Comment: Your answer is right and work correctly; now I have another question, I want redirect all page to `/` url when user doesn't sign in, I can do this by put a sending request to all page and get response `401` form server and then redirect, but I think it's very novice. How can I check this validation in `angularjs` code?

Comment: The logic is always the same